# How to fix 'PERCENTILE' formula in cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 cells that are supposed to take the percentage from a column range in a table. Each cell is supposed to represent a number value of 1,2,3,4,5 respectively. This is how it is supposed to be formatted:

1 = 0-20%

2 = 20-33%

3 = 33-50%

4 = 50-70%

5 = 70-100%

Here is how I have the current formula for each cell, with the appropriate percentage value for each:

`=IF(ISERROR(PERCENTILE($N11:$N2208,0.2)),"",PERCENTILE(IF($N11:$N2208>0,$N11:$N2208),0.2))`

Pictures of each output:

[Formula and current outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXTAE.png)

Column for percentages input:

[Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOvjD.png)

I am not sure what is wrong in my formula but I know it is wrong since 1,2 & 3 have the same output values. Also, the 100% value is 427% and the 20% value is 2.33%, this just doesn't make sense.

Can someone tell me what is wrong or why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

i stay away for complex excel formulas if i can spell the math out myself.
If cells A1=1, A2=2, A3=3, A4=4,, A5=5

```
 B1=TEXT($A1/MAX($A$1:$A$5),"0%")
```

B1 = A1 / the max value in range (5) then convert to a percentile
hope this helps.

Comment: changing the values to what I need (range of column N), would it be `=TEXT($N11/MAX($N$11:$N$2208),"20%")` for 20%?

Comment: Leave it as 0% meaning only digits before the decimal, where as 0.0% percent means all digits before plus only one after and 0.00% means all digits before plus two digits after. And as for MAX($N$11:$N$2208)  I'm not sure where the starting cell is. Say it starts at row 5 then it would be =TEXT($N11/MAX($N$5:$N$2208),"0%"). If you don't want this dynamic solution you could also go for =TEXT($N11/5,"0%") which staticly means 1 out of 5 or 2 out of 5 and so forth. The MAX() is just a nice way of allowing future edits without changing formulas